# Looking for event that can trigger my popup on press enter or when my marker is active in vue2 leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, leaflet

I am working on leaflet map and trying to show popup (<l-popup), when I press ENTER key and also when my marker is on active state then when on Enter press the popup show popup.
I have looked through leaflet map doc : https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/components/LPopup.html#demo
but cannot find any props or event that do what I want.

```
 <l-marker
          v-for="(loc, index) in locations"
          :key="index"
          @keydown.enter="openPopupOnEnterPress(index)"
         // @keyup.enter = "showPopup = true"
    
        >


     data() {
   return {
      showPopup: false,
   } 
}


methods: {
    openPopupOnEnterPress(e) {
      if (e.keyCode === 13 || e.key === "Enter") {
        alert("Enter was pressed");
      } else {
        console.log("Enter was not pressed");
      }
    },
}
```

The event or the function openPopupOnEnterPress(e) doesnot event triggers at all.
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Try to add `tabindex="0"` to **l-marker**

Comment: @Vasile Radeanu, tried with the tabindex="0" but still doesnot have anythingwhen I press   Enter :(

Comment: Sorry forgot about native event `@keydown.enter.native`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<l-marker
    v-for="(loc, index) in locations"
    :key="index"
    @keydown.enter.native="openPopupOnEnterPress(index)"
    tabindex="0"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks again. I tried with   '@keydown.enter.native ' and also 
'@keyup.native.enter' but when pressing on Enter nothing triggers, atleast some console mesg should have shown but its empty.

Comment: `@keyup.enter.native` not `@keyup.enter.native`, it should work if cursor is focused on element, make sure you have clicked on it.